# How to stop a div from inheriting parent css style

Tags: html, css

I have two .SCSS stylesheets contributing to one website. This is so that i can have a base, and a home stylesheet.

In the base style sheet, div has a float of left, however in the What We Do section i would like there to be no float. i cant seem to fix the issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hbyeyv6y/

Here is the Base .scss -

```
body, html, div, nav, section, ul, li, header { float: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
```

Here is the What We Do .scss -

```
div.whatwedo { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0 auto; background-color: #366e81; padding: 100px; text-align: center; width: 100%; }
    div.whatwedo .inner { float: none; }
    div.whatwedo h1 { color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Franklin Gothic', 'Arial', 'sans serif'; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 45px; }
    div.whatwedo h2 { margin-top: -15; color: #8e8e8e; font-family: 'Franklin Gothic', 'Arial', 'sans serif'; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 25px; }
    div.whatwedo h3 { margin-top: -15; color: #fff; font-family: 'Franklin Gothic', 'Arial', 'sans serif'; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 20px; }
    div.whatwedo p { margin: 0 auto; color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Franklin Gothic', 'Arial', 'sans serif'; font-weight: lighter; font-size: 15px; max-width: 500px; }
    div.whatwedo hr { border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; margin-bottom: 50px; width: 100px; }
    div.whatwedo div.container { vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; text-align: center; }
    div.whatwedo div.container img { margin: 50px 25px 0 25px; width: 231px; height: 231px; }
    div.whatwedo div.container p { margin-top: 20px; display: block; max-width: 210px; }
```

Comment: You overwrite `float` for `div.whatwedo .inner`. It's right, whre is the problem?

Comment: Thanks Panther, when i do that however, my background becomes half white, and the content is still not centered.

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/2ajx83b.jpg

Comment: maybe it's not the best way to set the float all these tags - body, html, div, nav, section, ul, li, header { float: left; }?

Answer (score 2):

As said, you could do `float: none !important;` and `initial !important;` for other rules.
But if you want to write good code, asigning float to body, html and so on doesn't look like a good idea. Float breaks the usual behaviour of the elements and it can lead you to unexpected results. You could add clases like:

```
.f-left{
   float:left;
}
```

only to the elements you want to float.

Answer (score 1):

`.whatwedo` is not floating - all it's parents and all it's descendants are though. Setting a float on everything is bad; why do you need to float everything?

Even so, to answer your question - you can unset the float for all `.whatwedo`'s descendants with the wildcard selector ...

```
.whatwedo * {float: none;}
```